# What is the exact difference between SizeRootFs and SizeRw in Docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-api

In the list of docker containers you can get the container sizes SizeRootFs and SizeRw, but I can't find what the sizes exact mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SizeRootFs` is the total size of all the files in the container, in bytes. If you were to export the filesystem of the container as a tarball, it would be about that size.

`SizeRw` is the size of the files which have been created or changed, if you compare the container to its base image. Just after creation, this should be zero; as you modify (or create) files, this will increase.